# How to compare the coordinates of a location to the current coords of a user

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cllocationmanager, cllocationdistance

I'm comparing the coordinates of a location to the current coords of a user. The distance is outputted like: 6056609.511004132946254686

I'm not sure what measurement this is in. I want the final measured distance to be in km.

```
 // location of deal
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latNum longitude:lngNum];

// user's current location
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLatitude longitude:currentLongitude];

CLLocationDistance distanceToDeal = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];
```

Comment: for what reason was this downvoted?

Comment: @АртёмЦарионов -1 because it's a textbook example of "this question does not show any research effort". If you pull up the help on this method, there is a one sentence description of the return code: "The distance (in meters) between the two locations." It couldn't be more clear. People should read the documentation before posting questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As described in the [Apple doc](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLLocation_Class/CLLocation/CLLocation.html) the distanceFromLocation function return value in meters. So the thing you have to do is to convert meters to km ;)

```
CLLocation *locA = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:latNum longitude:lngNum];
CLLocation *locB = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:currentLatitude longitude:currentLongitude];

//Compute distance in meters
CLLocationDistance distanceToDeal = [locA distanceFromLocation:locB];

//Convert meters to km
double km = distanceToDeal/1000;
```

Answer (score 4):

The most cursory read of the documentation would have made this clear. If you turn on the Quick Help Inspector (in Xcode 4.5, press <kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>option</kbd>+<kbd>2</kbd> or select "Show Quick Help Inspector" from the "Utilities" section of the "View" menu), and then click on `distanceFromLocation` in your code, it gives you the documentation for this method right there, which makes it clear that it's in meters. Alternatively, hold the <kbd>option</kbd> key as you move your mouse over the `distanceFromLocation` method in your code, and then click (while still holding down the <kbd>option</kbd> key) you'll see an online help popover.

Before you post a question here, you really should look at the Apple documentation.

Answer (score 2):

In meters, from Apple documentation:

`CLLocationDistance`

> A distance measurement (in meters) from an existing location.

`typedef double CLLocationDistance`

> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and later. Declared In CLLocation.h